# Does Michael Moorcock's Elric pass Bechdel test?

Tags: bechdel-test, elric-saga

Michael Moorcock positions himself as a strong pro-feminist.

As such, one would expect all his works to pass Bechdel test with flying colors.

Does "[Elric of Melniboné](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Moorcock#Elric_of_Melnibon.C3.A9)" (which Wikipedia calls his most popular works) pass the [Bechdel test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bechdel_test)?

Side note: for people who insist that I explain "why I asked this question": The question arose **out of a claim on a pro-feminist web site discussing what passes and what doesn't pass the test, with the un-backed-up claim that Moorcock does not**:

> Elric saga by Michael Moorcock: I think the term used by some other posters was, appropriately enough in this instance, "epic fail".  [Src](http://antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/2008/07/bechdels_law.html)

Comment: It's been a few years since I've read these books, but as I recall it's not even close.

Comment: I like the question, not sure why so many are down voting it. It might be better phrased to question the legitimacy of the Bechdel Test itself. I mean, is there an equivalent test for racism, i.e. a book is racist if it doesn't have minority characters talking to each other about something other than a non minority character?

Comment: @DVK: nope. Should I have done? My criticism here is because I disagree with your "Moorcock's a feminist, so you'd think his books would pass the Bechdel test" premise. Before you added the detail about the other website's claim (which I *have* read - I asked you to add it!), the premise seemed to be the reason for the question. The Tolkien question doesn't have a premise that I disagree with (I've no opinion either way on Tolkien's promotion of womens rights, or the value of the Bechdel test), hence no criticism there.

Comment: I'd disagree with the suggestion that an arbitrary test is the measure of whether a book or film is suitably feminist.

Comment: @Richard - what does the agreement with such suggestion have with the question being asked (passing or not the test)?

Comment: @DVK - The OP describes the fact that it may or may not pass the test as "epic fail" despite the fact that many feminist tracts would also fail.

Comment: *Gravity* fails the Bechdel test. The test isn't really suited to the evaluation of individual works as being 'sufficiently feminist' or whatever claptrap, but is rather useful in the aggregate to describe a significant and disturbing trend in the film industry as a whole.

Comment: In the case of Moorcock, this question becomes interesting as showing how his fiction change as he matured as a writer.   It's not an end-all-be-all question, but it's a good conversation starter.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on when he wrote the books.  The early ones certainly did not.  Late ones, like *Revenge of the Rose* and *Fortress of the Pearl* do pass the test.

Other *Eternal Champion* novels do pass the test, most notably the *Jerry Cornelius* and *Dancers at the End of Time* books.

Comment: Can you provide specific examples of why specific novels do/don't pass?

Comment: That's a tall order :)  I'll add a few from memory, my Moorcock books are in storage at the moment.

Comment: The Elric books generally fail for the same reason as a lot of Hollywood movies - lack of 'cross chatter'.  The protagonist talks to people, or they talk to the protagonist.  Secondary characters don't talk much amongst themselves.  If the protagonist is a woman, this conversation structure means it will likely pass.  If the main character is a man,it fails.  This conversation structure is particularly noticeable in Iron Man 2.  Two major female characters and they only share about three sentences in the whole film.  Stories which have an 'ensemble' feel pass more often.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [following definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bechdale_test) of the test:

> "The Bechdel test asks whether a work of fiction features at least two women who talk to each other about something other than a man"

They pretty much don't, if only because the Elric stories rarely feature two female characters who interact with each other.

In the early Elric stories female characters such as Cymoril, Shaarilla, Yishana, Zarozinia rarely, if ever, appear with other women so there's no opportunity for the BT to be assessed. Of course, it's possible for a work to fail the BT and still be pro-feminist and in this instance, while some of Moorcock's early female characters are stock one-dimensional 'damsels in distress' types others, such as Mrs Cornelius, Una Persson, Miss Brunner, the Rose, etc., are more self-reliant and often more competent than male characters in the same stories (i.e. Jerry Cornelius, Oswald Bastable).

Probably the obvious Moorcock novel to apply the BT to would be *The Adventures of Una Persson and Catherine Cornelius in the Twentieth Century*, but even then Una and Catherine's adventures take place in alternating chapters so their interactions are mostly limited (iirc) to the start and end of the novel. You might also check out *Gloriana*.

Comment: By that light, Galadriel makes LOTR feminist (being self reliant and pretty much the ruler of her Elven realm).